# How can I get a correct coordinate of a wide road in Android

Tags: android

I hope to develop an location based android app to get current location coordinates and display landmarks near the location , the road you are traveling etc. My problem is that, if someone is traveling in a wide road -the left,right and middle coordinates of the road may vary.As a result of this it may give incorrect road name. Therefore how can I get a correct coordinate of that particular road. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

One Option: Image recognition. Determine the actual width of the road based on images and update your landmark positions accordingly.

Another option. I'm assuming you have the gps coordinates for the landmarks, why not just show the landmarks at the actual gps coordinate. If the coordinate is "off-screen" then have a bubble or box or an arrow pointing off screen towards the landmark until it is "on-screen"

Comment: Thanx Sababado. From your answer I got a solution for my problem... Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.If i didn't answer your solution completely can you upvote?